# Error: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString text]:

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitextfield

I get this error when I will send the text content in UITextField to my dictionary. But I can't see what's wrong in this code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *newDrink = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[newDrink setValue:self.nameTextField.text forKey:NAME_KEY]; // error here
```

What can be?

Comment: Is nameTextField a UITextField or is it an NSString ? Looks like its not a UITextField.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I bet `self.nameTextField` is nil.

Check that.

Also, when attempting to access superclass member variables or properties from a subclass, make sure to create an instance variable (in your case, named `nameTextField`) in the superclass and see if that solves your problem.  [As this iPhoneSDK.com thread says](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/53261-unable-access-superclass-member-variables-subclass-implementation.html#post344717), "this is a very specific issue that crops up when you synthesize a property without creating an instance variable."

Comment: You can call methods on nil objects in Objective-C, your app won't crash - it will just ignore the call. However, if you release an object and then try to call a method on it... then it will crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS!

Comment: You're correct, self.nameTextField is nil. I'm inheriting of another UIViewController. And in this UIViewController I have IBOutlet's of UITextField... and everything work perfectly. But in this subclass, is nil. Why? I don't have XIB for this controller, I want use the same xib of my superclass. When I inheriting I lose the connections between IBOutlet and UITextField?

Comment: Wrong answer. Objective-C for beginners... If the method returns an object, then a message sent to nil returns 0 (nil).  See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW7

Comment: In this case, I should disable the ARC?

Comment: I like the cut of your jib, Ashley.  At least Mayckon now knows he's got a problem in attempting to set a nil value for a key.

Comment: Mayckon, I wouldn't disable ARC (nor do you need to release `nameTextField`... I don't think the compiler would allow you to call `release` with ARC enabled). Anyways, you need to figure out why nameTextField is nil. Where is it set?

Comment: In the superclass(UIViewController)

Comment: Create an instance variable named `nameTextField` in your superclass and see if that solves your problem. I found this probable answer [on this iPhoneDevSDK.com thread](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/53261-unable-access-superclass-member-variables-subclass-implementation.html#post344717).

Comment: I already have an instance of nameTextField and a @property too. The problem continue...

Comment: Resolved. In WillViewAppear I was sending the value of the dictionary but it was not for nameTextField for nameTextField.text .... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `self.nameTextField` has been released, and the memory partially overwritten so it looks like a `__NSCFString`.

Check that nameTextField is retained correctly.

Comment: I'm using the ARC. I don't release the nameTextField.